# Issue with Deployed Event Monitoring App: Deployed Datasets Missing in Production's Data Manager

Tags: event-monitoring, shield, crm-analytics, data-set

I have developed an Event Monitoring App in Analytic Studio in a QA Sandbox, and it is functioning correctly, displaying data on the dashboards. Recently, I deployed the app to the Production instance using a ChangeSet. The ChangeSet included the following components:

- Analytics Application
- Analytics Dataflow
- Analytics Datasets
- Analytics Lens
- Transaction Security Policy (including the Flow Version)

The deployment of the ChangeSet to Production was successful. However, I encountered an issue where none of the 57 Datasets are appearing under the Data Assets tab in the Data Manager. Consequently, when attempting to run the Dataflow, the following error is encountered.

Error: Something went wrong while executing the ExtractAPIFile node: Error in GetEdgemartCurrentData for edgemart API [error category: USER]: No edgemarts found with specified URL:esObject/edgemart?current=true&alias=API (02K8d000001JjuTEAS_03C8d0000049ZjDEAU)

I have recently started working with Salesforce Shield, so I need some help regarding this, please have a look at the attached screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]